# How to change the title font of Ant Design card component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How can I change **only** the title font but retain the default font for the child of the Card component of Ant Design?

**Sample Card component:**

```
// How to change title style
<Card title="Default" extra={<a href="#">More</a>} style={{ width: 300 }}>
  <p>Card content</p>
  <p>Card content</p>
  <p>Card content</p>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`title` property of [`Card`](https://ant.design/components/card/#Card) accepts `ReactNode`, therefore you can render any react component in particular its style:

```
import { Card, Typography } from 'antd';

const { Title } = Typography;

const App = () => (
  <Card title={<Title level={2}>Custom Title</Title>}>
    <p>Card Content</p>
  </Card>
);
```

> `title`- Card title   - `string|ReactNode`

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]